# How can I export mesh to UE

Tags: unreal-engine

I used particle system but particle system not possible export to fbx. Instead this I used convert to mesh now I can't to export. Export from Blender works, after want import to UE I got Import failed. No polygon were found on mesh  'Mesh'

I selected Mesh, I selected objects, I selected Targent Space.

I forgot something?

Regards

Comment: Doesn't UE have it's own particle system that is (for game making) superior to Blender's? Pardon my suggestion, but wouldn't it be easier to create the particle system in UE instead?

Comment: I'm not talking for weapons,... I'm talking for grass. I used grass using particle system, and in my case I want to import to mesh. So I have my grass in Mesh (I converted from particle system to mesh) and then I need this mesh to import in UE. How can I resolved this?